# SQL query show all IDs regardless if present or not

Tags: sql, left-join

I have a very basic SQL question. There are two tables: products and inventory. If I search on the products ID in the inventory table (using a left join shown below) I get all the product IDs (names) which have quantity in the inventory. But I would like to have shown all the product IDs and if they are not present in the inventory then have a 0 or Null as quantity.

Right now my code only shows the IDs which have quantity in the inventory table

```
Select A.ProductID, A.Name, B.Quantity
From Production.Product A
Left join Production.ProductInventory B
On A.ProductID = B.ProductID
Where B.LocationID = 1
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: please tag database you are using, also add some sample data and expected result

Comment: Use `inner join` instead if u have both product id's in both tables

Comment: to achieve the condition 'B.LocationID = 1' 'Production.ProductInventory' table should have valid record so remove the where condition

Answer (score 3):

You have to move predicate

```
B.LocationID = 1
```

from `WHERE` clause to `ON`:

```
Left join Production.ProductInventory B 
   On A.ProductID = B.ProductID AND B.LocationID = 1
```

If the predicate is in `WHERE` then `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN`, since for `NULL` records the predicate will not evaluate to `TRUE`.

So, your query will be:

```
Select A.ProductID, A.Name, B.Quantity
From Production.Product A
Left join Production.ProductInventory B
   On A.ProductID = B.ProductID AND B.LocationID = 1
```

This returns *all* `Production.Product` records. Field `Quantity` of `Production.ProductInventory` is returned by the query only when `ProductID` fields match **and** `LocationID = 1`, otherwise `NULL` is returned.

Comment: what difference it makes, it will return same results

Comment: @BHouse No, it won't. If the predicate moves to `ON` then `LEFT JOIN` will still be a `LEFT JOIN`.